# Offline payment gateway process

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, offline, payment-processing

What is the process of offline payment gateway. I got the one side process from internet. 
User will enter first and final 4 digit of credit card and giving cvv code, filling other relevant details then submit.

It will reach to to the admin side, I want to know what is the process happening admin side for receiving and completing the process.

I saw some woocommerce plug in for WordPress, but I didn't clear what is happening in other side.

Thank You

Comment: Offline payment gateway typically would mean that you're going to accept an order online that will be paid offline, like via a check or money order that is mailed. In that case, obviously you hold the order until payment is recieved.

If you're wanting to take credit cards, store them, and then run them manually through a terminal later... this is not allowable by PCI compliance standards.

If I'm entirely off base... try adding more details?

Comment: @Practically thanks, I want to know how it 'run manually' ? means, need to do anything with bank or with admin page? please tell me 'What you mean by terminal'? And why its 'not allowable by PCI compliance standards' , there are plug-ins for using this type of payment gateway though ?

Comment: Responded via answer, for formation options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to treat this question as a business logic one more so than a technical one. Based on information provided, I see two possible scenarios:

**Scenario One - Storing CC#s for later**

You're wanting to collect credit card information to process later via a terminal. Like a POS system inside a store or a web portal where you can type in the information.

This would be very difficult to make compliant with [PCI-DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). The cost of maintaining a PCI complaint system, much less setting it up, tends to be prohibitive except for the largest of companies. You need to use a service, like [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/), [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/), etc etc. Depending on the platform you're developing the website, all major credit card processors should have tools for a simple integration.

**Scenario Two - Accepting offline payment methods**

This would be a usecase where you want to allow users to pay via mailing a check or some other form of physical payment. This would just mean adapting your shopping / payment experience to allow an option to pay that method, provide a mailing address, and putting a hold on the purchase from processing further until payment is received.

This is what I have based on what was given so far, if I am off base, please elaborate!

Comment: so far I think you are correct. I found a plug-in for offline payment, I think this will reduce my work  http://www.wplab.com/plugins/offline-credit-card-processing-woocommerce/. Let me know your suggestion on this.

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri
That plugin seems to comply with the basic PCI compliance standards, but at the end of the day your credit card processing provider will make that determination. I would follow up with them and make sure, in writing, that your proposed implementation will satisfy them.

If you already have a credit card processor, why not investigate if they can work with authorize or another pay processor to accept payments directly on the site? That way you can take advantage of more traditional, and accepted, methods.

Comment: basically i am a designer, so I don't know much about the process behind this. I am planning to implement this with 'Stripe' payment gateway. I don't know this is sounds good, due to lac of knowledge. Anyway thanks for the support. If you have experience in this, please tell me which method to follow. I need online and offline to implement.

Comment: @AkhilNamboothiri If you're implementing stripe then you should be collecting payment via WooCommerce's stripe plugin on the site. If you need to process card present orders that happen in a physical store, than you can use Stripe's administration console that you login to on their site. Though for better processing fees its always ideal to get a card present system in place for your store front, and many local merchant service providers have more competitive rates than what you find online. Its acceptable to use stripe online and something else for POS / instore for the best rates for each.

Comment: this is a payment system implementing for a non-profit organizations website, in donations page. Not for any eCommerce. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Check into [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) rather than woocommerce. They have a stripe plugin available too but the user experience is much better if it doesn't fit eCommerce.